# If $u$ is an endomorphism such that $\exp(u)=\text{id} + (e-1)u$, is $u$ a projector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ a $\Bbb K-$normed vector space ($\Bbb K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) with finite dimension $n$ with $n > 0$. If $u$ is a projector of $E$ then : $$\exp(u)=\text{id}_E + (e-1)u .$$

> What about the converse: If $u$ is an endomorphism of $E$ such that $\exp(u)=\text{id}_E + (e-1)u ,$ is $u$ a projector ?

Here $e$  is the Euler number $e=\exp(1)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \simeq 2,71828183 ...$

Comment: What is $e$ in this context?

Comment: @Bepiop: The converse for me in the question is: conversly if $\exp(u)=\text{id}_E+(e-1)u$, is $u$ a projector? Thank's..

Comment: @ Bernard I  edited to explain what means $e$ (The Euler numbre: $2.71...$ )

Comment: @Bebop This is not a counterexample: if $u=\text{id}_E$ then $\exp(u)=e\,\text{id}_E=\text{id}_E+(e-1)u$.